# I am trying to change author nickname by bot in discord using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots, airtable

I am trying to change author nickname using a bot which I had coded in discord.js. I am unable to do it and I am getting error as I am getting data from airtable. The bot has admin permissions to make changes as coded. My code is as following

```
console.log(usernameclan);
console.log("Old user is here");
member.roles.add(rolenumber).catch(console.error);
msg.author.send("Welcome to the clan");
let id = msg.author.id;
client.channels.cache.get(channelnumber).send("Welcome to the clan" + "<@" +msg.author.id+">");
//msg.author.setNickname(usernameclan);
//message.guild.members.get(bot.user.id).setNickname("some nickname");
```

The commented portions are 2 attempts done by me to change the message author's nickname. The bot and user interaction is happening in the direct messages of the user. How to change the user nickname? I have also tried this code here  I am open to any solution which would work. I had also tried this in my code

```
let guild = client.guilds.get(serverId);
let student = guild.member(msg.author); 
let nickname = student.setNickname(usernameclan);
```

Comment: Direct Messages do not give `message.member`. Do you want to select a guild to convert the user to a member in,  then change their nickname?

Comment: @MrMythical I am open to any solution which would work. I had also tried this in my code let guild = client.guilds.get(serverId);let student = guild.member(msg.author);
                let nickname = student.setNickname(usernameclan);

Answer (score 1):

You may not change the nickname in a direct message so my exact implementation here would be

```js
member.roles.add(rolenumber).catch(console.error)
<msg>.author.send("Welcome to the clan" + "<@" +msg.author.id+">")
// This
<client>.guilds.cache.get("Guild ID").members.cache.get(<msg>.author.id).setNickname("some nick");
```

Comment: Please note the <> are added since your definitions of client and message / msg here can be different you may change them.

Comment: I am getting a error message like this E:\Projects\Git\Bot\node_modules\airtable\lib\query.js:118
                if (result.offset) {
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined
    at E:\Projects\Git\Bot\node_modules\airtable\lib\query.js:118:28
    at E:\Projects\Git\Bot\node_modules\airtable\lib\run_action.js:70:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5). your solution might be correct but it is not working here

Comment: [There is an open github issue dedicated to issues such as this](https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js/issues/246), this error is being thrown via a third party lib airtable which isnt discord.js / js I recommend adding airtable tag in it

Comment: thanks for bringing this to my attention as well that this is also open on  github.

Answer (score 1):

DMs do not provide a `.member`. You will have to get the guild, then the member from there to change their nickname.

```js
//msg is an instance of Message (received in DM)
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("the guild you want to change the member's nickname in")
const member = guild.members.cache.get(msg.author.id)
member.setNickname("new_nickname")
```

Comment: Getting error 
E:\Projects\Git\Bot\node_modules\airtable\lib\query.js:118
                if (result.offset) {
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined
    at E:\Projects\Git\Bot\node_modules\airtable\lib\query.js:118:28
    at E:\Projects\Git\Bot\node_modules\airtable\lib\run_action.js:70:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: The code I provided does not return that error. Make sure it is in an event callback. It’s likely that this is caused by other code

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it helped.

Comment: it helped in looking me at documentation in much better detail. Though yet getting the error but thansk for your time